# Maven Behavior when compiling twice without clean lifecycle

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Working with a multi-module maven project. Want to have separate maven `compile` & `install` logs. Thus executing steps as follows:

```
mvn clean compile
```

Followed by

```
mvn install
```

to run other phases in install lifecycle. Since `maven-compiler-plugin`(version 3.1) is capable of incremental compilation, is this execution right, or will it produce unexpected results? Do not wish to change execution if it works as expected(without skipping or compiling any file twice).

Comment: Simple answer: Not possible cause `install` (apart from usually not needed) contains `compile` phase (See [life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)) and separating the logs ? Apart from that all: Have you tried it?

Comment: Not possible as in compile would be running twice? Would not the second step leverage `maven-compiler-plugin`'s incremental compile support. From logs, my execution seems to be working fine, but  do not wish to exclude any plugin behavior that might be tied to goals for future builds

Comment: Are we talking about a CI usage here or a local usage? Furthermore have you checked compile-plugin output ? I also strongly recommend to use a more recent version of it. Have you simply tried to run `mvn clean verify` and afterwared `mvn verify` seeing the differences?

Comment: @ArpitJain You asked several questions on how to separate parts of the Maven lifecycle. But please note: Maven is not meant to be used that way. Maven is meant to run _once_ with a whole lifecycle from beginning to `install` or  `deploy`. Your approach of trying to split up Maven runs and put them together later may work, but you put a lot of effort into using Maven in a very special way...

Comment: @JFMeier I feel the last question was not "using maven in a special way". Using `maven clean install` followed by `mvn deploy -DskipTests -Dmaven.install.skip=True` is widely used. Just wanted to understand  whether install goal or install phase is skipped in the second step. Can use that knowledge in my maven configuration. Appreciate your help

Comment: It does not matter if it's widely used it's simply wrong and shows that those people who encourage that simply don't understand the Maven life cycle nor understand the best practice of Maven.