# Maven compile behavior when running `mvn install` followed by 'mvn deploy -Dmaven.install.skip=True'

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Working with a multi-module maven project. Executing following steps

```
mvn clean install
```

to check if program works fine(compilation, Unit Testing, installation), followed by

```
mvn deploy -DskipTests -Dmaven.install.skip=True
```

to deploy without installation. My question is, does `-Dmaven.install.skip=True` skips `install goal` or `install phase`. Will `compile phase` would potentially be running twice? Usiing `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.1

Comment: Another time the same question and don't read/heard the answers which have given and explained in detail how it works that the point https://stackoverflow.com/q/61756586/296328.